# Can I send an Anonymous SMS with Android?

Tags: android, sms

I would like to send SMS (with Android) with an anonymous sender number or a different phone number from the actual sender phone number. (e.g. sender phone number 123, received SMS will show 456)

Is that applicable ? Please attach a small sample code.

Comment: NO, you will have to find an external provider that supports this type of service, up until a year ago Clickatell.com supported users to enter any number as a SENDER number. this service is no longer available.

Comment: Wow!! I also want a BMW, if you have then pls send me a "Sample BMW".

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using the android API itself. You can however use some online SMS sending service.